# How to format future dates and times using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the following (via moment.js) to format a timestamp representing the current moment.

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

This gives me `2018-12-03T17:30:14`.

How would I format a timestamp for future days and times? For example, considering that today is Monday, how would I format Tuesday at midnight in the same way? And Wed, Thur, etc.?

I would like to get e.g. `2018-12-04T00:00:00` for Tuesday and `2018-12-05T00:00:00` for Wednesday. How would I do this using moment.js?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be achieved via the `.add()` and `.startOf()` functions like so:

```js
console.log( 
  'Tomorrow at midnight:',

  moment()
  .add(1,'days')  // Add one day (ie set moment instance to tomorrow)
  .startOf('day') // Set the time to midnight
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") 

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more information on these methods see these links:

- [Add method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)
- [StartOf method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

Comment: We'd also have to set minutes and seconds to 0 too, right? When you run your code it gives "2018-12-04T00:40:42".

Comment: I suggest to use [`startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to set to `0` hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.